# Tensorflow r1.0 control_flow_ops.with_dependencies() missing

Tags: tensorflow

control_flow_ops.with_dependencies() seems to be missing in the 1.0 release, can't find anything in the changelog about it. Should we not use the function anymore or was it replaced by something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `tf.control_dependencies()`: [TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies)

Comment: This could work (existed pre-1.0 release), not as convenient as the with_dependencies() function was. Unfortunately the docs still reference control_flow_ops here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm